# Is this the right way to setup up an image within a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $('<a />').attr({
        'href': '#'
    })
    .append(
        $('<img />').attr({
            'id'    : 'img',
            'src'   : 'edit.png'
    }))
    .appendTo('body');
```

Is the the "right way" to go about adding `<a href="#"><img src="edit.png" id="img" /></a>` to the body?

Also how would I add some css onto the img?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all that directly into the jQuery() since version 1.4.x

```
$('<a />', {
    'href': '#'
})
.append(
    $('<img />', {
        'id'    : 'img',
        'src'   : 'edit.png',
        'css'   : {
            'width'  :  '100px',
            'height' :  '30px'
        }
}))
.appendTo('body');
```

This even works with events and data, you can say

```
$('<div/>', {
     id:    'myID',
     class: 'myCLASS',
     css:   {
         position: 'absolute'
     },
     click: function(e){
         alert(e.target.id);
     },
     data:  {
         foo:  'bar'
     }
}).appendTo(document.body);
```

Comment: +1 - This works with events...but there's actually a bug with `data` in particular, e.g. it overwriting events when the object's extended.  You'll find the order matters when specifying `data: {}` :)

Comment: I know I was the one posting this on SO :), sadly the official bug report on this wasn't even assigned to anybody - yet.

Answer (score 0):

[TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) aside, yes, it is one way of doing it. Remember, there is no "right" right way. If it works, it means that you are on the right track.

Also, being right is relative.

Comment: It's not entirely relative here: One way could let through invalid or broken HTML (using only `$`); `attr()` will do validation of incoming input values.

Comment: There are several right ways, for sure. But there are certainly wrong ways as well. I really can't agree with "If it works, it's right"

Comment: Perhaps I was too general. Updated to better reflect my point.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<img/>').attr({
     'id'    : 'img',
     'src'   : 'edit.png'
 }).css({/* css here*/})
```

[more on `.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

Not really recommended  to do inline styles, but an example of CSS on an image is :

```
<img style="display:block;" src="##.jpg" />
```